# Displaying an "incoming call" screen with iOS SDK in background while using webRTC

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, voip

reading around I get the impression this may not be supported?

Basically what I'm trying to do is make a webRTC video/voice incoming call screen when my app is receiving incoming call signal from my xampp server. What I want to do is display a screen similar to skype with answer/hangup option.

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You mean a notification which you can then slide to the left (on the lock screen) to reveal additional actions?

Comment: not necessarily the lock screen, you could just be in another app and it'd interrupt whatever you're doing. I don't think a notification suites my needs because I can't customise the look of it.

I want to be exactly like an incoming regular call screen, except for my own design.

Skype and viber and many other VoIP supporting apps have that screen which fires when you have an incoming VoIP call, except I'm not technically using VoIP...

Comment: I was mentioning the lock screen just because the additional actions are not shown the same way in other circumstances. They would be shown while on the springboard or in other apps, just differently (swipe down if using banners, mostly). Is Skype actually showing a phone-like call screen when it is in the background/the device is locked?

Comment: @MikiBergin did you ever find out how to display the incoming call screen from the background?

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to implement this:

1. You can declare your application as VOIP. This kind of application is allowed to have one signalling socket working even in background mode; you should use setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: method as well in order to keep your socket connection active. As soon as new data will be ready for reading on this socket your application will be awaken and you can send local notification to let user know about incoming call. But this approach is deprecated and isn't battery friendly.
2. You can just make use of voip push notifications.

Have a look at [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH30-SW1) for mode details.